# Не выключается PC Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

После установки убунту и при попытке выключить PC, он просто зависает и не может его выключить. Приходится принудительно через кнопку выключать...

Comment: Сколько пробовали ждать? Что на экране написано в это время?

Comment: Появляется экран выключения и бесконечная загрузка.

Comment: Насколько бесконечная? Сколько пробовали ждать? Esc жмали?

Comment: Нажмите `escape`, возможно он завершает какие-то процессы. Например у меня иногда бывает, что минут 10, останавливает `mysql`

Comment: Не, тут именно в ядре, какая-то несовместимость. Есть подозрение на видео, но надо покавырять.

Comment: Так Esc жмали-то?

Comment: Вроде да, но для полной уверенности сейчас еще раз нажму.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAxLW5piZwD6vA без изменений

Comment: А вот это уже действительно грустно. А в какой момент вы жмали Esc? Сразу после появления логотипа или подождали?

Comment: Сразу нажал и после этого еще пару раз.

Comment: Пойдём другим путём: в файле `/etc/default/grub` найдите `"quiet splash"` и замените на `""` (пустые кавычки), обновите загрузчик `sudo update-grub`, перезагрузитесь и попробуйте ещё раз — тогда логотип убунты выключится и можно будет без Esc прочитать что происходит (если я ничего не напутал)

Comment: Сейчас попробую, до этого пытался дописать acpi = force, но не помогло.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/zANWO5MivwnL0r вот что появляется.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305

Comment: У него это ошибка при включении системы, а у меня при выключении.

Comment: Ребят, все дело в драйверах на видеокарту, пошаманив с ними, стало все работать.

Answer (score -1):

в черном экране XD

CTRL+ALT

в терминале вводишь логин пароль

пишешь

```
$ sudo nano /etc/dafault/grub
```

нам нужна строка

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

меняем это "quiet splash" на это "nomodeset"

потом CTRL+X

сохранить изменения Y
потом вводишь

```
$ sudo update-grab
```

потом  вводишь reboot

перезагружаемся

Comment: 1. Это есть в комментарии. 2. Если я правильно понимаю, оно не устраняет проблему, а лишь даёт возможность прочитать какое-то сообщение? // cc @aleksandrbarakin

Comment: рабочий сама тестила )

Comment: @aleksandr,
тут задача стоит в том что после установки черный экран 
Это или ошибка загрузчика что может быть связано в bios или иная нам надо перезаписать загрузчик

Comment: перечитайте текст вопроса, пожалуйста, обратив внимание на заголовок и данный фрагмент: «при попытке выключить PC, он просто зависает». и там и там речь о том, что компьютер не выключается. да, в комментариях, кажется (рисунки уже недоступны), затрагивается и тема включения. но вопрос-то касается именно выключения.